# PHP dom replacement

Tags: php, html, dom

I have been looking for some time now and haven't been able to come up with anything. I have a page that contains both html and php.

```
<div>%%replace_me%%</div>


<? replaceStr("replace_me", "foobar"); ?>
```

I need a function that would change the above %% string into foobar to make the html look like this:

```
<div>foobar</div>
```

The text will *Always* be surrounded by percentage signs but not always enclosed in a div. There will be php on the page as well as the %% vars, so storing the page in a $var and str replacing hasn't worked for me.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Can't you just use `<?php echo "foobar"; ?>` instead of `%%replace_me%%`?

Comment: @mtahmed "I need a function that would change the above %% string into foobar to make the html look like this"

Comment: @even No; I need the function as it will change depending on what page you are on

Comment: Why can't you use Regular Expressions to achieve this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @mtahmed and regex what var? That is part of my question. I don't know how to store the html (which contains the replacement php) in a var.

Comment: Can't you just echo a variable, and set the value of that variable at the top of the page? Or use in an include file? Or just echo what is necessary like evan said? I don't see why you would need a function to do this, unless you are trying to load in and process an existing HTML file for some sort of templating system.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a template engine.  [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a popular one for PHP.  There are [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20template%20engine) as well.

Understand that within the context of the server-side code (PHP) there is no "DOM" or even really "HTML" in the sense that you're implying.  There's HTML in the .php file, but you can't really interact with it like that.  It's just text in the file waiting to be served down to the client after the PHP engine interprets the PHP code.

DOM parsing and all that stuff happens in the browser once the content is delivered to the client, which is after the server-side code has run.  There are [PHP DOM parsers](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20dom%20parser) as well, but they're for consuming HTML and manipulating it within the PHP code, not for interacting with the HTML markup that's outside of the PHP code in the same .php file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add `ob_start()` near the beginning of your page to ensure that output is buffered and not sent to the user until you've had a chance to parse it. I would then try to collect all calls to `replaceStr()` until all possible `%%` tags have been output and you're ready to replace them all in one shot. Then, this should do the trick:

```
function replace_str(&$body, $tag, $replace) {
   str_replace('%%'.$tag.'%%', $replace, $body);
}
$body = ob_get_clean();
replaceStr($body, 'replace_me', 'foobar');
// other calls to replaceStr...
echo $body
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Although if you are looking for something more robust, I would definitely still look at David's answer.